# how to fade out and fade in more than 90 columns? without crashing the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

My problem is I have a table with 9 columns, and the last two have colspan, divided into 90 and 60 columns.
I wanted to implement the [columnManager plugin](http://p.sohei.org/stuff/jquery/columnmanager/demo/demo.html) because I wanted to hide these big columns. And when the user wants to see one of them, he would click some button to show all the 90 columns, or the 60 columns.
Before that I tried the [toggle function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) with jquery.

In both methods I'm able to hide them but if I tried to show them, the scripts takes to long to load and stops.

So I need to thing about other strategies..

If anyone has any idea how to solve this I would appreciate.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had too much information on these columns and the toggle didn't work, I had to figure out another approach.
The only way to work is to divide the table into several tables.

Each sub table belongs to a cell of the major table, and that way I can put an id into the td and toggle the td.

Give unique ids to the columns doesn't work since these columns are divided into 90 and 60, and have lots of data. the script will stop half way through

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you be better off using regular tables.

The way I would do it would be to give the two columns i wanted to hide unique id and using the jQuery `toggle` function show and hide them.

Comment: That was my first approach, but these columns has so much data that the script stops

Comment: the toggle works but not the way you're saying. I post an answer, hope you can understand. cheers